# App for iPad and Android

Tags: feature-request

Why Physics Stack Exchange don't create and application for mobile devices?, I understand that all people have a web browser inntheir device to check all the stuff, but, with an mobile application you can create a whole lot of options, like use the keyboard to write equations like wolfram alpha do, for example.

Comment: By the way, welcome to Meta. Don't take the downvotes too seriously - they don't really count for much here, so people are pretty free with them. In this case they probably mean "this belongs on the [network-wide meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)" but of course the response there might be "well if you want the feature, why don't you help develop it yourself?" Developing a bug-free, *non-exploitable* app on a new OS is a nontrivial task for a team of developers.

Answer (score 3):

This would be done at the Stack Exchange level, and in fact [they *are* working on an Android tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app). Don't know if or when a iOS version might be in the works.

Comment: Of course, getting a math keyboard would be a second hurdle -- I doubt they'll do that for the main app. I think Android has some TeX keyboard plugins.